# subprocess.Popen does not execute all lines of a shell script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

code:

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(['sh',shFile],stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out,err = proc.communicate()
```

Problem:

shFile in line 1 runs several shell scripts. When I execute shFile from bash, all the shell scripts are executed. However when I execute it using subprocess.Popen, the last shell script is not executed. Interestingly the last line of the shFile is "echo 'Done'", which gets executed.

The last 6 lines of shFile are:

```
sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__20_eval.sh
sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__5_eval.sh
sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__20_eval.sh
sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__15_eval.sh
sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__10_eval.sh
echo "Done"
```

Only decoder__10_eval.sh is not executed. If I change the order of the scripts, once again the last one fails to execute.

Comment: I was able to identify the trouble, I failed to close the file after writing the last decoder__ script. Thus subprocess was trying to run a script before it was completely written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subprocess does not do any magic. Note that `sh` is often *not* bash on modern Linux systems, but a lightweight shell such as dash. If your shell script is bash-specific, you therefore need to change `'sh'` to `'bash'`.

In any case, it is *extremely* unlikely (less likely than winning the lottery ten times in a row) that `sh` (or `bash`) would "forget" to execute a line in a script. Also make sure that `shFile` is what you expect.

Looking at your updated script, the error is almost certainly in the scripts you evaluate. For example, they might simply run out of temporary files or other inadvertently shared resources. Please post the `decoder__` scripts, or reproduce the problem with shFile containing:

```
/bin/echo sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__20_eval.sh
/bin/echo sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__5_eval.sh
/bin/echo sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__20_eval.sh
/bin/echo sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__15_eval.sh
/bin/echo sh /export/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/decoder__10_eval.sh
echo "Done"
```

If the "10" output is missing, then you've really got a problem with sh. Otherwise (and again, with extremely high certainty), the problem lies in the tempScripts you're executing.

Comment: I tried reducing the number of decoder__ scripts to check if it is a resource problem, but even with reduced number of scripts the last script always fails to execute.

A sample decoder__ script is as follows :

    `cd /export/Experiments/hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/decoder__10`
    `sh decoder.sh eval > /export/Experiments /hierMultiStream_audSpec_direct/tempScripts/n_10.out`
   

The doubt if it is a problem with the decoder__ scripts, as I pointed out before that on changing the order of scripts they run fine, except for the current last script.

Comment: On running with /bin/echo in the beginning of the command, it prints all the decoder__ scripts, including the last one.

Comment: @Vijay If it's not a problem with the decoder scripts, you should be able to reproduce the problem with the shFile I suggested. Can you? Also, why are you having this mess of nested shell scripts in the first place? Isn't it easier to call `decoder.sh` directly from python, rather than to call a shell script that calls another temporary shellscript, which calls *another* shellscript?

Comment: @Vijay The /bin/echo experiment proves that Python is not at fault here. As I said, try reducing the unnecessary complexity introduced by the high number of nested shell scripts. If that doesn't work, ask a question where you detail how the last script fails to execute (for example, if you add `echo "$@" >> /dev/shm/log` to the top of it, is something written?)

Comment: the nested scripts were required as the original scripts produce several thousand lines of output, which could cause deadlock problems with subprocess.communicate. 

However I was able to identify the trouble, I failed to close the file after writing the last decoder__ script. Thus subprocess was trying to run a script before it was completely written.

Thanks for your help.